# How can we read the content of html file which is stored in views folder in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to load the html file stored in views folder in laravel.
I just want to get the path of that html so that I can read the content.

Is there any way to do this?

for a workaround am storing that html file in storage folder and reading the html content. But as I said this is just a workaround for me.I need to store that in views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just get the html content of a view, you can simply do:

```
$html = View::make('your_view');
```

While, if you want to get the content of a json file (as you've asked in the comments), you should put it in the storage folder and get its content with:

```
$content = Storage::get('file.json');
```

Comment: why would you put raw json data in a view ?

Comment: I am not putting raw json in view I have a json file within views folder i just want to get the content the same way we can get for html file using  "make" method.

Comment: The question stated that you wanted to read an HTML file, not a JSON one. However, if you have a json file, you should put it in the `storage` folder and get its content with: `$contents = Storage::get('file.json');` Not sure that `View::make` will read it properly

Comment: Thanks, I kept my html in views and json in storage it is working properly now :-)